# Обучение азам дизайна сайтов

Tags: дизайн

Всем здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, советом, книжкой, видео-уроком чем-нибудь, мне нравится делать сайты, но сайта без дизайна не бывает, так вот у меня с этим огромная проблема, я знаю на нормальном уровне css и могу многое **реализовать**, но у меня большая беда, я не могу придумать дизайн для сайта, вот посмотрите это мой сайт

[image]

Я не понимаю, откуда берутся идеи для дизайна, как подбираются цвета? Какие картинки надо искать для сайта и много много много ещё подобных вопросов. Товарищи дизайнеры поделитесь, пожалуйста, информацией, где это всё вы берете? Очень хотелось бы научится хотя бы придумывать красивые дизайны.

Comment: - Если бы дизайну можно было научиться по видеоурокам, то вряд ли бы существовала профессия дизайнера как таковая.

- На практике, использование штук типа `bootstrap` позволяет сильно уменьшить вероятность того, что на сделанный вами сайт можно будет лепить плашку "говнодизайн / сказочный высер".

- Извините за мой мой французский :)

Comment: Ну сайтец скажем мягко не ухты. А если по вопросу, то тогда всему учишся с практикой. Пытайтесь учиться на фотошоп-уроках, мне это действительно в своё время помогло.

Comment: И зачем минусовать вопрос?

Comment: *(По поводу скриншота сайта)*

- Градиенты - долой, рамки у блоков - выкинуть или сделать намного менее явными.
- Статистика сайта никому не интересна, кроме вебмастеров.
- Время генерации страницы никому не интересно, кроме разработчика.
- Регистрацию по `OpenID`.
- Отзывы замучаетесь модерировать.
- Поправить русский язык ("Внимание, акция", "алмазов(-а)", ...)
- Убрать фамильярный стиль "хорош болтать".
- "Акция" - это разве не новость? Почему одни новости у вас посередине, а другие справа? Много ли кому вообще будут интересны ваши новости?
- Баннеры на всю шапку - признак порносайта

Comment: - Много букаф в новостях, лучше кратко и емко (http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/141/)
- http://yvision.kz/post/77772

Answer (score 3):

- [designm.ag](http://designm.ag/)
- [webdesignledger.com](http://webdesignledger.com/)
- [smashingmagazine.com](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)
- [webdesign.tutsplus.com](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/)
- [designshack.net](http://designshack.net/)

Answer (score 3):

**Чтобы писать красивые сайты необходимо:**
 -  Не говорить, что вы что-то знаете на высоком уровне, даже если это и так есть. Любой "компьютерный язык" - развивается, особенно в последнее время Веб. Знаете поговорку "Глупец думает, что он действительно умен, а мудрец знает, что он глуп";  
 -  Вдохновение. Это как искусство, к этому надо подходить творчество. Хорошим примером может быть "написание произведений". Многие люди пишут произведение свои, только после того, как они прочитали других авторов. Т.е в Вашем случае Вам необходимо по бродить по сайтам и попытаться "понравившийся дизайн" с "рипнуть", только со своей изюминкой; 
 - Чтобы писать оригинальничавшие сайты Вам необходимо проявить фантазию. Скажу по своему опыту мне хорошие идеи приходят ночью "в 3 часа ночи" =). Не ограничивайте "Стандартами". Не делайте похожий сайты на другие; 
 - Для реализации красивого сайта, не надо наляпесто делать весь цветной сайт. Делайте все скромно, возьмите примером дизайн Google, [Vk.com](http://Vk.com)...
 - Для улучшение дизайна ознакомитесь со всеми свойствами CSS3 и новыми тегами в HTML 5;
 - Если брать Ваш сайт, то я рекомендовал бы разделить цветами блок.( На шапку и контент), также убрать градиент, оставить шапку блока темную, а зону контент - белый

Удачи Вам, помните я писал сугубо свое мнение, а также помнить в каждом правиле есть исключение, не придерживайтесь всего моего списка строго =)

Comment: vk.com или же vk.ru?

Comment: Спасибо, отпечатался, исправил

Comment: @Node_pro, хотя у vk.ru тоже дизайн норм.:)

Comment: =),  но там более насыщено)

Answer (score 1):

Цветовые схемы можно поподбирать [тут](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

Comment: и тут: [kuler.adobe.com](http://kuler.adobe.com/)

Answer (score 1):

- Почитайте теорию цвета где-нибудь. Благо таких учебников много.
- Затем долго и упорно что-нибудь рисуйте в фотошопе по урокам из интернета, так научитесь рисовать именно на компьютере, и поймёте возможности графических редакторов.
- Затем идите на [dribbble.com](http://dribbble.com), возле каждой работы справа приводится использованная гамма цвета, оттуда же берите и свои идеи для работ. С некоторым временем голову станут посещать уже свои идеи для работ.

Дерзайте :)

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете получить вдохновение на [Hourspent.com](https://www.hourspent.com)
К сожалению, я не владею русским языком, я бы объяснил лучше